# Why does Exec() run the command in parallel?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to understand why #1 executes the statements in parallel, but #2 executes them one by one unless I open a query window for each of them in SMSS. Can someone enlighten me?

```
#1 
Exec(xp_cmdshell.... blah);
Exec(xp_cmdshell.... blah);

#2
select .... from xyz;
select ..... from abc;
```

Answer (score 2):

#1 should not be running in parallel. BOL says

> xp_cmdshell operates synchronously. Control is not returned to the
>   caller until the command-shell command is completed.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/libRary/ms175046.aspx

Comment: weird! Unless my understanding of parallelism is mistaken, it does. For example, when I execute #1 calling BCP, you can see it writing to two separate files at the same time. Whereas, if I do something like... insert into #output xp_cmdshell bcp.... it writes to a single file at a time.